# GNOME Full screen notifications

Tags: debian, gnome

When I watch a YouTube video in full screen or use steam in-home streaming, I can't see the notifications at the bottom of the screen. Additionally, for in-home streaming, I can't use my windows key to switch to overview. I want to be able to do these things at all times. How can I accomplish this?

Debian Jesse x64